# Preserving transparency when using imageformat.memorybmp

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I'm combining 2 images, first image will be the canvas and the 2nd image will be the overlay. Both of the images doesn't have an actual file, instead it's generated and stored in memorystream.

**Canvas**

```
 MemoryStream canvasStream = new MemoryStream();
 var canvas =  new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
 canvas.Save(canvasStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

**Overlay**

This is a smaller than canvas and it will be place at the middle of the canvas. It will look like a picture frame or simply and image with 20px padding.

```
 MemoryStream overlayStream = new MemoryStream();
 var canvas =  new Bitmap(overlayWidth, overlayHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
 canvas.Save(overlayStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

After saving to the memorystream, both of these images Imageformat defaults to **Imageformat.MemoryBmp** not **Imageformat.PNG**. Hence, losing the transparency.

**Combine Canvas and Overlay**

```
        Bitmap combinedImage = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(combinedImage))
        {
            graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphic.Clear(Color.White);

            int BGCanvasXCenter = 0;
            Rectangle rectDest = new Rectangle(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);

            if (fixSize)
            {
                // center image
                BGCanvasXCenter = (canvas.Width / 2) - (overlay.Width / 2);
                rectDest = new Rectangle(BGCanvasXCenter, 0, overlay.Width, overlay.Height);
            }

            var imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
            imageAttributes.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

            graphic.DrawImage(
                overlay,
                rectDest,
                0, 0, overlay.Width, overlay.Height,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                imageAttributes
            );
        }
```

Is there a way to preserve the transparency when using memorystream? How do I set the imageformat to PNG?

Please take note that the requirement is not save an actual file during the process, that's why i'm resorting to memorystream.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This `var canvas =  new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);` is enough to create a bitmap in memory. No need to create a `MemoryStream` nor `canvas.Save(...);`.  Use them to create the output image then save the output image `outputImage.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.png);`

Comment: `Imageformat.MemoryBmp` is unrelated to transparency; it just means a `Bitmap` _object_ (Not file. Not BMP format. Just `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class object) created in memory, rather than loaded from file data. I suspect that if you are losing transparency, it is due to the way you combine them. Which **you did not include in your question**.

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks, I will do code clean up after. Btw, Im dealing with JPEG images and trying to save the PNG converted image to the stream for further processing.

Comment: @Nyerguds I've updated the code. I've checked  Imageformat.MemoryBmp rawformat attr and it's set to JPEG. But after combining the images, combinedImage  rawformat is now PNG.  However, when its rendered in the browser it becomes JPEG again. I'm suspecting this could be caused by response mime type.

Comment: @Nyerguds yeah the mime type in the header response was the culprit!  thanks for helping. :)

Comment: response mime type? You didn't mention a word about web-related stuff in your question... and you use `System.Drawing`, which is generally advised against on server technology because it uses GDI+ objects.

Comment: @Nyerguds sorry if i didn't mention that this is a web app. Anyway, I'm creating an image handler that that will fetches images from S3 and then resized to whatever size the user requested. The challenge is to keep the image aspect ratio and resizing the image to requested size.  Thanks for your inputs

Comment: As mentioned though, `Bitmap` class is a GDI+ object, and those are, by their nature, not managed by the garbage collector. You have to be _very_ careful to `Dispose()` _any_ `Bitmap` object you create, from the moment you no longer need it (so probably right after you send it as data), otherwise you're creating a memory leak and your application will start crashing once the internal GDI+ object limit is reached. This is one of the reasons the use of `System.Drawing` is not advised for server applications.

Comment: Well this memory leak is actually happening now. Now I need to dispose every bitmap!  does `using ()` help?

Comment: `Bitmap` objects should _always_ be cleaned up, as a rule,  yes, and the simplest way to do that are indeed `using()` blocks. but in this case, it's not enough. [There are a lot more problems once you get over that one](https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet). MSDN explicitly states that **[Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing)**